# Simplify CSS Statement?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a joomla-website and I have problems with one CSS statement. The website uses several menus which have different names. Because of that, I would have to do something like this:

```
a#ext-gen1.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current,
a#ext-gen2.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current,
a#ext-gen3.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current,
a#ext-gen4.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current {
    //...
}
```

To simplify this, I was thinking of replacing the numbers with a *, which would work if the statement is treated like a shell-command. The result would be this:

```
a#ext-gen*.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current {     
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. So how does something like this in CSS work?

Edit: The HTML-File looks like this, if that is important:

```
<a href="./some/link.html" class=" ux-menu-link-level-0 current ux-menu-link-parent " title="" id="ext-gen5">
some text
</a>
```

Comment: Why not select class only? 
`.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current {     
    ...
}`

Comment: Because that doesn't work. I need to tell the style-sheet that it's a link. In your example the "a" is missing.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work, but you can add the `a` selector: `a.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current { ... }`

Comment: Have you got the context for this? without seeing the source and the other css/html, it's difficult to tell what would be appropriate.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I added it to my post

Comment: You really need to show the page, or at least create a jsfiddle containing the whole page's html and css. Otherwise, we can't know if there are other elements that also have the classes `ux-menu-link-level-0 ux-menu-link-parent current`, etc.

Comment: @ialarmedalien http://felsenmuseum.at/index.php/sonderschau/aktuell

Comment: Which menu items is the styling being applied to? And what is the styling to be applied?

Comment: To the 3 menu-points with a sub-menu: "Museum", "Sonderschau" and "4kids". Styling is just highlighting them in terms of background-color and font-color.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the "begins with" CSS selector. This will select all elements with an 'id' that begins with "ext-gen".

```
a[id^="ext-gen"] {}
```

Comment: I have really no idea how to exactly implement this and if I just copy and paste this, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Exceen Edited the CSS cause I didn't use your exact starting id name.

Comment: This might be being overridden by some ID selector given it has less specifity. @Exceen you should use your browser's developer tools to see if that is the case

Comment: @ZachSaucier He copy/pasted my original CSS which didn't have the exact id name. That's more likely why it didn't work for him the first time and I don't think he tried it the corrected way.

Comment: This doesn't work either :/ | Also: I really need to place the ".current" there, because I want to select only the currently browsed menu-point.

Comment: @Exceen Then you have a lot more going on there than can be gleaned from your example and only a link to the actual page will do. I'm not sure that you can simplify your example while still showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`a.ux-menu-link-level-0.ux-menu-link-parent.current{}` should do fine.

```css
div.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
div#d1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="b" id="d1"></div>
<div class="b" id="d2"></div>
```